# remove_pointer for unique_ptr's

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, unique-ptr, dereference

Suppose I'm writing a board game with a playable AI.  `class Board` takes two template parameters: P and N.  N is the number of players.  P is either `unique_ptr<Player>` or `Player`.  I use `unique_ptr<Player>` when actually playing the game, because `Player` has two child classes (`Human` and `AI`), but when the AI searches game states, it uses the same `Board` class but with T = Player (I chose this for a potential performance gain, e.g. data will be local, less indirections, and heap should be less fragmented).

**Question:** How would I define the operator[] which returns a reference to one of the players (e.g. if T = unique_ptr it returns *arr_[i], else returns arr_[i]).  Below is an attempt, but doesn't compile. Also, feel free to comment on design (e.g. in theory, can I really see a performance gain by introducing P?).

```
template<typename P, size_t N>
class Board
{
public:
  P& operator[] (size_t idx) { return helper(arr[idx]); }
private:
  template<typename I, typename O>
  inline O& helper(I& input)
  {
    return input;
  }
  template<>
  inline P& helper<unique_ptr<P>,P>(unique_ptr<P> input)
  {
    return *input;
  }
  std::array<P,N> arr_;
};
```

Compiler errors:

1. explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'class Foo'
2. template-id helper,T> in declaration of
       primary template

Comment: The performance impact of dereferencing a pointer compared to search through the space of game states should be negligible and probably lost because of the duplication of code, due to having two versions of `helper()`. I would not bother with that.

Comment: Your `Board<Player>` would slice the child classes. And what exactly is `T` in your code?

Comment: Use [`std::remove_pointer<P>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer) to generate the reference type and put the definition of the `helper` template at namespace scope.  Alternatively, partially specialize `Board` for `P *`.

Comment: @5gon12eder OP wants it to work for smart pointers, not just plain pointers.

Comment: @T.C. Oops, missed that point.  Then  you'll have to code your own (simple) `remove_unique_ptr` template.  I think the rest of the comment remains valid.

Comment: @T.C. Sorry, there's no T.  I meant to say P.  And what do you mean by "slice child classes"?  I know my post wasn't clear, but the game state search won't call any virtual methods, I can use the parent class Player.

Comment: There are three argument modes for objects. (1) by-value: do not use. (2) by pointer: use if and only if you want to be able to pass a null value. (3) by reference: use in all other cases. The performance difference between (2) and (3) is zero. Don't play tricks with yourself like this. It isn't worth it.

Comment: @EJP The difference in this case is array<Player,N> and array<unique_ptr<Player>,N>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't comment on the logic behind this, but implementing it just requires introduces a helper function: and using the helper's return type. The problem you're seeing in your attempt is that your operator[] just returned `P&` - which will be the wrong type if `P` is a `std::unique_ptr<T,D>`.

To use the helper's return type, we just make it private static and rely on `decltype`:

```
template <typename P, size_t N>
class Board {
private:
    template <typename T, typename D>
    static T& get_helper(std::unique_ptr<T,D>& val) { return *val; }

    template <typename T>
    static T& get_helper(T& val) { return val; }

public:
    decltype(get_helper(std::declval<P&>())) // use the same return type
                                             // as the helper function
    operator[] (size_t idx) {
        return get_helper(arr_[idx]);
   }

private:
    std::array<P,N> arr_;
};
```

In C++14, the commented out line can be just `decltype(auto)`.

Answer (score 0):

> > > Also, feel free to comment on design (e.g. in theory, can I really see a performance gain by introducing P?).

OK here goes:

1. You are attempting to trade maintainability for performance even before the code compiles. This is early optimisation at its most evil.
2. unique_ptr manages ownership. To use it as a logic switch as you're seeking to do is trading maintainability and readability (big time) for an as-yet unconfirmed performance increase (see 1). The only reason to pass a unique_ptr to to a function is if the function **absoluteley must know** that the data is being managed by a unique_ptr. This is rare (read: never do it) unless you're transferring ownership or you're writing a visitor which is designed to visit a collection of unique_ptrs
3. The most important things about code are these (in order of importance):

   1. It compiles
   2. It works
   3. It's logically correct, bug free and does not leak resources
   4. It's easy to maintain
   5. It really is easy to maintain
   6. Your users enjoy using it
   7. At this point you're allowed to attempt to fulfil your narcissistic fantasy about writing the most efficient code you can write (usually for no good reason). You will fail and you really do have better things to do - like making the game better and more fun to play.

The time to worry about performance is when your users are so spoiled with flawlessly working software which is a such joy to use, that the only thing they can think of to worry about is that the game is only giving them 299.99 frames per second and they reckon it really should deliver 300.

Comment: Just FYI, I tested this change extensively today.  3 before/after tests, each with 3 compilers, each with 3 optimization levels, for a total of 54 test runs.  One test was calling the copy constructor 1 million times and storing the copies in a vector (simulates actual usage), and the new method 40%-50% faster across the board (much higher than I expected).  As explained in the OP, I believe this is due to extra calls to "new" on each copy.